# How to display string as date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column(string (8)) that contains data like 12032008 and I have to display it as 12/03/2008. What should I do in retrieve query?

Comment: Ideally you convert it to a `DATE` column and then do the date formatting client-side in whatever quirky date format the user wants.

Comment: Does `12/03/2008` mean December 3rd, 2008, or March 12, 2008?

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate thing for you to do here would be to stop storing date information in text columns.  Instead, put `12032008` into a bona fide `datetime` column.  This will make your life easiest in the long run.  If you can't do that in the short term, here are two options for you to consider.

The short way, just using base string functions:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LEFT(col, 2), '/', SUBSTRING(col, 3, 2), '/', RIGHT(col, 4)) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The longer way, and probably the better long term solution, would be to first convert your date string into a date, then convert it back to a string using the formatting you want:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(col, '%d%m%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

In mysql first convert it to date object using `STR_TO_DATE` then to format use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('12032008','%d%m%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')
```

But ideally you should not save the date or date time as strings in table it will make things complex for mysql and for you also

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DRR41858)